# Why is are these expressions in Leibniz notation not equivalent?

Tags: calculus, integration, classical-mechanics

I have this problem, a projectile is fired into fluid with a rate of deceleration $a=-0.4v^3$ and in initial velocity $v_0=60$.

We are to find how fast its going after $t=4$ seconds.  If one starts with: $a=\frac{dv}{dt}=-.4v^3$, and advance to $dt=\frac{dv}{a}$, we can integrate $$\int_0^tdt=\int_{60}^v\frac{1}{-0.4v^3}$$

Integrating, this produces a correct answer of: $v=0.559$.  However, when I set up an even simpler (looking) equation, the problem becomes: $adt=dv$, such that $-0.4v^3dt=dv$.  The integral becomes:
$$\int_0^t-0.4v^3dt=\int_{60}^vdv$$
solving for this equation produces a different, incorrect answer.  What causes this?

Answer (score 1):

In the second equation you propose you are integrating v^3 in dt on the l.h.s. but you cannot do that since v is an unknown function of the time. You can't just assume it doesn't depend on t. The "correct" expression of what you wrote should be 
$$\int_0^t -0.4v^3(t)dt=\int_{60}^vdv\ ,$$
but that's simply an involved way to write the differential equation
$$\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=-0.4v^3(t)$$
with initial condition $v(0)=60$.